# What's a good name for a class that takes network commands and executes them?

Tags: naming-conventions

So say I have this class that is just responsible for taking NetworkRequest's and handling their execution on a given server... what do I name it? I can think of lots of verb names but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetworkCommandExecutor
NetworkRequestDistributor
CommandDistributor
RequestDirector
GeneralSchwarzkopf